# Why doesn't this flow type definition work?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to type everything using flow.  With this code, it's saying that the comma on the 2nd line is an "unexpected token":

```
const WizardNavGuide = ({ index: number, 
                          steps: Array<string>,
                          classes: any }) => {
```

What's wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing typing with [object destructing alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

What you wanna do is this:

```
const WizardNavGuide = ({ index, steps, classes }: {index: number; steps: Array<string>; classes: any }) => {}
```

Or this:

```
interface Props {
  index: number;
  steps: Array<string>;
  classes: any;
}

const WizardNavGuide = ({ index, steps, classes }: Props) => {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I remember reading about this "extra code" when an object is involved but forgot about it.  Much appreciate your help.